# Node.js app on Heroku experience a lot of H12 errors

Tags: node.js, heroku

I can't seem to figure out why I get `H12` errors throughout the day. I see the consoles showing 30000ms for a response and my Heroku starts calling.  If I debug the exact same route in postman....responds in under 300ms.

Please, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This generally occurs when you have a long async process. Heroku imposes a 30 second timeout on all of its routes. If no data is received in that time, then it sends the H12 error.
I had faced this issue while scraping a lot of social media data for a website. I installed [expressJS timeout](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout) so that timeout errors are caught at dyno level. This stops the server from crashing.

However, the timeout error would still remain. To get rid of that, investigate the code to find which route you're having the timeout issue with. Heroku has given a few tips here: https://help.heroku.com/AXOSFIXN/why-am-i-getting-h12-request-timeout-errors-in-nodejs

Explain your exact problem here, as in what you are trying to accomplish with your NodeJS app in order for more specific help to be provided.

Comment: The thing is these are routes that normal take 30ms....As i sit and watch the server...things are going fast then all of a sudden the exact same routes start showing a 200 with a 30000 timestamp.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do in your route? Some sample code or a better explanation would help

Comment: Do a username lookup...a route that normal is really fast.  It uses a connection from the mongodb pool....runs a query and returns back the user

Comment: I also notice that my CPU usage spikes to 116 %

Comment: Try reducing the number of records you have to scoure through by adding additional search parameters. Such as date of birth or last name.

Comment: Also, node version should not matter

Comment: thanks....but it not the query...its something else....and its random routes that normally work 95 percent of the time